# Locate Twitter Posts in the feed with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following script to like a post (from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ovFudqFB0Q), once that the bot has already logged in on Twitter:

```
def like_tweet(self, hashtag):

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://twitter.com/search?q=" + hashtag + "&src=typed")

    time.sleep(3)

    for i in range(1,3):

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(2)

        tweets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet')                           
        links = [elem.get_attribute("data-permalink-path") for elem in tweets]

        print(links)
```

However, variable links is printed as an empty list. How can I obtain a list of posts links for a specified hashtag?

Can I define tweets and links differently in order to achieve the result?

Comment: is `tweet` the name class in twitter's HTML? I can't find any tag with class name `tweet` (on latest twitter interface

Comment: How can I change that so that the script works?

Comment: Here `tweets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet')`. But I suggest properly understand the script, because you are going to have to make a lot of changes

Comment: I understand; but how can I change that line so that it works?

Comment: you need to find the correct class name for tweets from HTML source. See in this section (photo of Chrome DevTools) to see how to select the correct class name for your tweets. Then update the line to `tweets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('CLASS_NAME')`

Comment: what hastags are you trying to search? because your code works fine for me. when i run your example searching for the phrase "halloween", i get 2 lists printed. the first list has 40 results, and the second list has 60. each list's links are in a format like `'/NeinQuarterly/status/1186761224878542851'`